# Hibernate entities configuration into WEB-INF

Tags: java, hibernate

I need to put hibernate entities configuration xml, into the WEB-INF directory.

The /hibernate.cfg.xml is into the directory: **/WEB-INF/hibernate/**

The entities configuration files are into: **/WEB-INF/hibernate/entities/**

What I have to write into the tag `<mapping resource="/WEB-INF/hibernate/entities/book.hbm.xml" />` to load correctly entities configuration?

I receive this error:

```
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: resource: /WEB-INF/hibernate/entities/book.hbm.xml not found
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check your application folder in tomcat webapps, I think `book.hbm.xml` is not in the directory it's supposed to be in.

Comment: I've checked just now, it's into the directory. I'm using maven. and  GlassFish as AS.

Comment: If the file is in place even in exploded webapp directory, then it should work. Did you check if there's any typo in the path ?

Comment: You can try using a relative path like `entities/book.hbm.xml` in `mapping`

Comment: Yes, I've checked and the path isn't wrong. thanks to your answer. I've resolved by adding "../" into the path which has become: "../hibernate/entities/book.hbm.xml"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved by adding "**../**" into the path which has become: "**../hibernate/entities/book.hbm.xml**"

Thanks to all.

Comment: You can even use `entities/book.hbm.xml` that way you don't have to go back to WEB-INF.